# How to simplify the expression $x\sqrt{x}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

How to simplify the expression $x\sqrt{x} =$? Learning the basics for maths.

Comment: Should that be $\; x\cdot\sqrt x\;$ , meaning: the product of $\;x\;$ by the square root of $\;x\;$ ?

Comment: Do you mean $x\times \sqrt{x}= \sqrt{x^3}$?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I mean

Comment: According to the [Stack Exchange Network Terms of Service](http://stackexchange.com/legal), "Subscriber certifies to Stack Exchange that Subscriber is an individual (i.e., not a corporate entity) at least 13 years of age."

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche Yeah...great disclaimer for kids, who could care less about those legal things.

Comment: @Joanpemo ...and great information for kids who didn't know there is an age limit.

Comment: In the USA this is probably at least 8th grade, and more likely 9th or 10th grade level.

Answer (score 2):

$$x\cdot\sqrt x=x\cdot x^{1/2}= x^{1+\frac12}=x^{3/2}=\sqrt{x^3}=\left(\sqrt x\right)^3$$

You can now choose the form you like the most: they all are the very same thing.

Answer (score 0):

$x\sqrt{x} = \sqrt{x^3}$ since $\sqrt{x}$ is defined by the way you write it then x>0.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/623953)

Comment: He edited the post after we answered.